# making use of template library 1.4.1 in codeigniter 2.1.4

Tags: php, templates, codeigniter-2

I am newbie to codeigniter. What I am trying to do is to make use of template library 1.4.1 into codeigniter. 
          I have downloaded a template library 1.4.1 and copied respective template.php in config,libraris and views folder of codeignitor.
here is what I have done so far
    template.php in config folder:-

```
    $template['default']['template'] = 'template';
$template['default']['regions'] = array(
                                        'header' => array(
                                                          'content' => array('<h1>Welcome</h1>','<p>Hello World</p>'),
                                                          'name' => 'Page Header',
                                                          'wrapper' => '<div>',
                                                          'attributes' => array('id' => 'header', 'class' => 'clearfix')
                                                          ),
                                        'content',
                                        'footer',
                                        );
$template['default']['parser'] = 'parser';
$template['default']['parser_method'] = 'parse';
$template['default']['parse_template'] = FALSE;

controller :-  
  <?php
class Page extends Controller {
   function index()
   {
      $data['title'] = "My Real Title";
      $this->template->render('title');
      $this->template->render();
   }
}
?>
```

when I run my program it shows me a blank page.
and used header footer in html code. Can anybody please tell me how to make use of template library and where I am getting wrong ?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kindly have a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to SO & come back again with your efforts & specific problem you face.